# Is Graql compiled or translated to gremlin?

Tags: sparql, gremlin, vaticle-typedb

I'm wrapping my head around Grakn a little to understands its added value, I wonder if Graql is compiled or translated to gremlin traversal step ?

This makes me wonder about the difference of expressivity between Sparql and Graql, given that the former is until now not fully translated into Gremlin. It seems to be an open problem ? Is Graql fundamentally simpler than sparql and that would explain the fact that is it fully translated if that's the case ? If not is there any limitation in translating it to gremlin steps at this point ?

Comment: you should ask the Grakn devs whether Graql can be translated to Gremlin... although I don't understand why this is important for you?

Comment: For me, Graql is a query language designed only for their product Grakn whose underlying schema formalism is based on a property graph. It's part of a commercial product and not a W3C standard like SPARQL. I haven't seen a translation to Gremlin yet.

Comment: there is also GraphQL which people are working on right now

Comment: It is all about understanding the expressivity of grakn. Because it is back by property graph I want to know if you could do with graql everything u can do with gremlin, any traversal possible and maybe how contrived that might be. What is lost in translation what r the limitation. Does it generate efficient traversal ? Logic ground query language from datalog, to sql or sparql are easy to use but get translated to join operation as I have understood. Traversal, overall is more efficient and distributable partly because of the traversal based on micro-indexes.

Comment: Grakn somehow claim to bridge the gap between logic based query formalism including inferencing capability and traversal based approach. I want to understand the theoretical performance of that bridge and the benchmark.

Comment: *"understanding the expressivity of grakn"* - that is something that has to be formalized and proven. You should really ask the grakn/graql devs therefore. Even for other graph query language this hasn't been formalized nor proven. [Olaf Hartig](http://olafhartig.de/) did some first steps in defined semantics and expressivity for GraphQL. In general, he and other research are working in that area - you should read the publications.

Comment: Quite recently, there was a [seminar for knowledge graphs at Schloss Dagstuhl](https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/program/calendar/semhp/?semnr=18371) - feel free to also take a look at what they did.

Comment: Last but not least, very well-known people are working on a new language, called GQL - see https://gql.today/

Comment: I am hoping that Graphql people answer here, as in their website they suggest either the forum or stack overflow. But maybe i should go to the source. Gremlin is turning complete. It is not difficult to see that. Graql is  grounded on logic formalism. But yeah probably go ask at the source if they do not reply here indeed

Comment: GraphQL is not a graph query language, it’s a standard for streamlining access to APIs. But it “emulates the elegant simplicity of a graph database in terms of how it understands and exposes the data and application connections that the individual APIs represent”, according to Geoff Schmidt, the co-founder and CEO of Apollo.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to shine some light on your questions.

To begin with, Graql was designed to be a high-level, human-readable query language. The main idea was to abstract the node-vertex graph datastructure to concepts that are specific to a given user-defined domain. In that way the user doesn't need to worry about the underlying graph representation and low-level gremlin constructs and instead he can work with high-level terms he defined himself and/or he is familiar with.

Now, implementation-wise Graql is an abstraction over Gremlin which translates the high-level queries to Gremlin traversals which can then be executed against a specific graph. However, the mapping between Graql and Gremlin is not 1-1. In fact, Graql operates with some subset of Gremlin that allows to capture the intended behaviours of the Graql language. It was never our intention to find such a mapping as the goal was to translate high-level queries to queries understandable by the underlying graph processor.

Now the efficiency of the traversal generation. Graql queries can be decomposed to properties (has, isa, sub, etc) and fragments. Each fragment has a defined Gremlin counterpart and each property can possibly contain multiple fragments. Now the fragment translation is unambiguous, however there is a lot of freedom in picking and arranging the fragments that go into a property. Keeping in mind that queries contain multiple properties this makes the arrangement a strictly non-trivial task. To perform this arrangement, which in Gremlin is handed to the user, we implemented a query processor. The idea of the processor is to pick such an arrangement and ordering of the fragments that the resulting query execution is as fast as possible. This is reminiscent of SQL query processors and the motivation is exactly the same, to abstract the query optimisation from the user.

We are actively working on the query planning component and although it gives no guarantee to be produce the most optimal plan in all cases, we are trying to make the produced plans converge to optimal solutions.